# curl/wget stopped working (I didn't change anything), but exact same URL works in browser

Tags: curl, wget

If I go to this URL in browser:

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x3f349bBaFEc1551819B8be1EfEA2fC46cA749aA1&apikey=DJD6AQYBZTP197BBYKR5G4DDRH4YMQZKSX
```

it works fine, returning:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"60824359763526706"}
```

If I put the EXACT same URL in curl or wget, it gets 'Invalid API key' and I don't know why.  It's the exact same URL.

```
$ curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x61aE35Be08ea92f9263cDbA2Af0dBC1d4861d652&apikey=DJD6AQYBZTP197BBYKR5G4DDRH4YMQZKSX" 2>> /dev/null
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Invalid API Key"}

$ wget --timeout=15 -O - -o /dev/null "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x61aE35Be08ea92f9263cDbA2Af0dBC1d4861d652&apikey=DJD6AQYBZTP197BBYKR5G4DDRH4YMQZKSX"
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK","result":"Invalid API Key"}
```

I don't understand what happened here, since it was working a few days ago.

Comment: I am aware there is an API Key in this question, this is intentional, I didn't do this by mistake.  API Keys are free at bscscan.  I created a new API key just for this question and will delete it in a few days.  The account address is also not mine, but a random one I got from blockchain.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a new PC and the curl command works there.  Both the non-working PC and working PC have the exact same version of Ubuntu and the same version of curl.  Both curl -v (verbose) commands show the exact same output information except one PC works and the old one doesn't.  Very confused.

Comment: add `curl -v` on 1 of the systems where it doesn't work and post the output. my suspicion is that shell quoting rules fucks up the api key, the output of `curl -v "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x3f349bBaFEc1551819B8be1EfEA2fC46cA749aA1&apikey=DJD6AQYBZTP197BBYKR5G4DDRH4YMQZKSX"`  would prove-or-disprove my suspicion

Comment: What happens if you provide `wget` with url 1) without any quotes 2) with single (`'`) in placce of double (`"`) quotes?

Comment: Apparently it wasn't anything I did, because it started working again today.  I also emailed the BscScan team and they answered they are aware of an issue with a small subset of users and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fixed.  Apparently it was Bscscan problem.

[image]